# Semantic segmentation dataset inspection

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, statistics, visualization

Is there any tool that can calculate the statistics of semantic segmentation dataset (and possibly the similar types of datasets ...)?

So that it shows the number of classes, the total number of pixels for each class, and other similar statistics, ... and visualizes those statistics ...?